# NSRegularExpression: how to match XXX ... YYY?

Tags: regex, cocoa, nsregularexpression

I have tried

```
[[[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"XXX(.*)ZZZ" options:0 error:NULL]
```

but it is not working.

I want to match any sequences of characters between by two tags `XXX` and `ZZZ`.

Comment: What is not working?What's your input, current output and desired output?

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I got it ;-)

Comment: good habit to edit the question, but there is still not enough info. On what input are you using the regex? Please give concrete examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is... Don't forget the `NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators` if you want to match any sequence of characters !!!

```
     [[[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"XXX(.*)ZZZ" 
                       options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators 
                                             error:NULL]
```